# Get text between and outside angle brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have email addresses in this format:

`Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>`

I'd like to set `Jane Doe` as one variable and `jane.doe@example.com` as another.

Is this a regex situation, or is there a more elegant way?

The closest I can get is the expression `/\<(.*?)\>` which returns `<jane.doe@example.com>` (with the angle brackets).

Comment: Note that `<` and `>` should not be escaped. In some regex flavors the `\<` denotes start of a word and `\>` denotes the end of the word. Though it is not the case with PHP, it is best practice to only escape what must be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your pattern (or a bit modified version) to [*`preg_split`*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) the string and get an array with the 2 values:

```
$s = 'Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>';
$res = preg_split('/\s*<([^>]*)>/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($res); // => Array ( [0] => Jane Doe [1] => jane.doe@example.com )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NmNuho)

The `\s*<([^>]*)>` pattern finds 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with `<`, then captures any 0+ chars other than `>` into Group 1 (with `[^>]*`) and then matches `>`. The `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag makes `preg_split` keep the submatch (Group 1 value) in the resulting array. `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag will discard any empty items that can occur at the beginning or end. The `-1` *limit* argument will return all split chunks (no limit).

There is also a matching solution, and the one I'd suggest is with the *named capturing groups*:

```
$s = 'Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>';
if(preg_match('/^(?<name>.*\S)\s*<(?<email>.*)>$/', $s, $m)) {
  echo $m["name"] . "\n";
  echo $m["email"];
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/GO9yOg) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7mIdT/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<name>.*\S)` - Group  "name": any 0+ chars up to the last non-whitespace char followed with...
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `<` - a `<` char
- `(?<email>.*)` - Group "email": any 0+ chars, as many as possible up to the
- `>$` - `>` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

With `preg_split` and `list` functions:

```
$input = 'Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>';

list($name, $email) = preg_split('/\s(?=<)/', $input);
$email = trim($email, '<>');
var_dump($name, $email);
```

The output:

```
string(8) "Jane Doe"
string(20) "jane.doe@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using capturing groups you can match with following regex.

**Regex:** `([^<]*)<([^>]*)>`

**Explanation:**

- `([^<]*)` will capture name in 1st group.
- `([^>]*)` will capture email id in 2nd group.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SIPd1C/2/)**

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
   $line = "Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>";
   
   
   if (preg_match("/([^<]*)<([^>]*)>/", $line, $match)) :
      $name=$match[1];
      $email=$match[2];
      print "Name: ". $match[1];
      print "\nEmail Id: ". $match[2];
   endif;
?>
```

**Output**

> Name: Jane Doe
>
> Email Id: jane.doe@example.com

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/opjC96)**

Comment: Note that you do not need to use lazy quantifiers. `([^<]*)<([^>]*)>` will work well, too (and a bit faster).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes I realized that while coding in php. I will correct it in regex demo.